# The best way of return boolean value in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer.

I have a question about the way of returning a `boolean` value.

Which do you like? For what reason?

1.

```
public boolean methodA(List<String> targetList){
    boolean result = false;         
        for(String str : targetList){

            if(str.equals("word1")) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            if(str.equals("word2")) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

2.

```
public boolean methodB(List<String> targetList){
    boolean result = false;         
        for(String str : targetList){

            if(str.equals("word1")) {
                return true;
            }
            if(str.equals("word2")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not get rid of your boolean `result` altogether, and just `return false;` at the bottom of your example #2? Reads cleaner, in my opinion

Comment: After the Java and JIT compilers are done with this code, there maybe absolutely no difference. In general, start by writing code that's easy to maintain, and focus on improving your algorithms and data structures. Worry about micro-optimization only after you have things running and can see where improvements are needed.

Comment: It all comes down to how you like to read/write your code, I'm old school, I like one entry and one exit point for all my methods, consider if the code grows so that the return statements span multiple screens (you need to scroll), you can quickly loose track of or miss `return` statements which can make it difficult follow the logic, so personally, I prefer example #1

Answer (score 5):

```
public boolean methodABC(List<String> list) {
    return list.contains("word1") || list.contains("word2");
}
```

Comment: The only "problem" with this is that the list could at most be iterated through twice if word1 is not found

Answer (score 4):

This is what you end up doing once your code gets absurdly large:

```
public boolean methodB(List<String> targetList)
{
    for(String str : targetList)
        if(str.equals("word1") || str.equals("word2")) 
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is on point but your lack of curly braces is appalling.

Comment: @Makoto - ha! Does that shorthand drive you nuts? I find it less cluttering personally.

Comment: But there are so many good reasons for it. Extending the bodies, avoiding dangling else... Its like a safety net. Everyone needs one or two. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Using streams, a very simple one-liner:

```
public boolean methodA(List<String> targetList){
    return targetList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.equals("word1") || s.equals("word2"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second method is better, because if it finds the search term, it will not waste time going through the other values.

The best method for this would be:

```
public boolean methodC(List<String> list) {
    for (String str : list)
        if (str.equals("word1") || str.equals("word2")) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or in Java 8/1.8: (Correct me if this is wrong!)

```
public boolean methodD(List<String> list) {
    yes: {
        list.forEach(str -> {if(str.equals("word1") || str.equals("word2")) break yes;});
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for late to reply.
and I greatly appciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

`methodA()` is good cause it follows the single-entry/single-exit structured programming and iterates the list only once.

`methodA()` cleaned up:

```
public static boolean methodA(List<String> targetList) {
    boolean result = false;         
    for(String str : targetList){
        if(str.equals("word1") || str.equals("word2")) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`methodB()` is good because it's just a few lines shorter, iterates over the list once, takes up less memory (no use of result `boolean`, VERY MINOR memory save), returns immediately upon success.

`methodB()` cleaned up:

```
public boolean methodB(List<String> targetList){
    for(String str : targetList){
        if(str.equals("word1") || str.equals("word2")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

After learning about streams, a one-liner that follows the single-entry/single-exit structured programming and iterates the list only once.

```
public static boolean methodX(List<String> targetList){
    return targetList
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(target -> target.equals("word1") || target.equals("word2"));
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> targets1 = new ArrayList() {{
        add("hello");
        add("goodbye");
    }};

    System.out.println(methodA(targets1));

    List<String> targets2 = new ArrayList() {{
        add("hello");
        add("goodbye");
        add("word1");
    }};

    System.out.println(methodA(targets2));

    List<String> targets3 = new ArrayList() {{
        add("hello");
        add("goodbye");
        add("word2");
    }};

    System.out.println(methodA(targets3));
}
```

Results:

```
false
true
true
```

In regards to performance, they all iterate through the list only once so IMO it just comes down to personal preference as to which is best to use.  For myself, it would be `methodX()`